# PyQt5 UI Not Displaying When Loading From File

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am attempting to load the .ui file that I created. However, when I run my python app, the main window is empty. I believe that the issue is in the line where I am loading the actual file. In all of the examples that I have seen, you are able to just load in the file, if the .py file is in the same directory. However, this wasn't working for me, so I had to use the absolute path. This fixed the FileNotFoundError that I was getting, but now I have this issue.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys
import os

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        ui_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(ui_path, "myfile.ui"))[0]
        self.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

Myfile.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1141</width>
    <height>885</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QFrame" name="sidebar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>200</width>
      <height>720</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>16777215</width>
      <height>720</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(209, 102, 24)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>40</x>
       <y>170</y>
       <width>75</width>
       <height>23</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Graph</string>
     </property>
     <property name="flat">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="Line" name="line">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>200</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="lineWidth">
      <number>3</number>
     </property>
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="topbar">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>200</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>911</width>
      <height>135</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>911</width>
      <height>0</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>1920</width>
      <height>16777215</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color:rgb(12, 76, 173)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>430</x>
       <y>70</y>
       <width>113</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
     <property name="placeholderText">
      <string>Search</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="body">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>200</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>911</width>
      <height>591</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color:rgb(255, 254, 247)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: share myfile.ui ....

Comment: @eyllanesc I just updated it to include myfile.ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/uic/uic-module.html#loadUiType) points out:

> **loadUiType(uifile, from_imports=False, resource_suffix='_rc',
> import_from='.')**
>
> Load a Qt Designer .ui file and **return a tuple of
> the generated form class and the Qt base class**. These can then be used
> to create any number of instances of the user interface without having
> to parse the .ui file more than once.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

This returns 2 classes and will not fill any window, instead of using loadUiType you should use loadUi as pointed out by [the docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/uic/uic-module.html#loadUi):

> **loadUi(uifile, baseinstance=None, package='', resource_suffix='_rc')**
>
> Load a Qt Designer .ui file and **returns an instance of the user
> interface**.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        ui_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(ui_path, "myfile.ui"), self)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.